# A prime numbers property: $4/\pi=e^{1/2}\Big(1+e^{1/3}\big(1+e^{1/5}(\dots)\big)\Big)/p_n, \ \ n\to\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, pi, euler-product

It is possible to show that the limit of the following fraction is a constant $$ \frac {e ^ {1/2} \Big (1 + e ^ {1/3} \big (1 + e ^ {1/5} (1 + e ^ {1/7} (\dots (1 + e ^ {1 / p (n)})} {p(n)} \sim c $$
How can I determine the value of the constant $ c $?

$ \ $

From the prime number theorem we have that $ \pi (x) \sim \text {li} (x): = \int_0 ^ x \frac {dt} {\ln (t)} $, where $ \pi (x ) $ is the prime counting function. $ \pi (n) $ can be thought as the inverse of the function $ p (n) $ which gives the $n$-th prime number, such that $ p (n) \sim \text {ali} (x) = \text {li} ^ {- 1} (x) $. Calling $ \text {ali} (x) $ the inverse function of the logarithmic integral:
$$\text{li}(\text{ali}(x))=x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d}{dx}\Big[\text{li}(\text{ali}(x))\Big]=1\Rightarrow \text{ali}'(x)=\ln(\text{ali}(x))$$
$$\text{ali}''(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\Big[\ln(\text{ali}(x))\Big]=\frac{\text{ali}'(x)}{\text{ali}(x)} \Rightarrow \text{ali}'(x)=\text{ali}(x) \text{ali}''(x)\sim p(x) \ \text{ali}''(x) $$

Solving the differential equation $ y '(x) = p (x) y' '(x) $ we obtain:

$$y(x)=c_2+c_1\int_{1}^{x}\exp \Big(\int_1^{t}\frac{du}{p(u)}\Big)dt$$

Interpreting the integral as the area under a broken line, we can write for the integer $ n $:

$$y(n)=c_2+c_1\sum_{v=1}^n \exp\Big(\sum_{w=1}^{v}\frac{1}{p(w)}\Big)\sim p(n)$$

$$y(4)=c_2+c_1 \Big( e^{\frac{1}{2}}+e^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}+e^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}}+e^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}}\Big)=c_2+c_1 \Big( e^{1/2}\Big(1+e^{1/3}\Big(1+e^{1/5}\Big(1+e^{1/7}\Big)\Big)\Big)\Big)\approx 7$$

This means that $ \big (y (n) -c_2 \big) / p (n) \sim c_1 $. Setting $ c_2 = 0 $, the trend of $ y (n) / p (n) $ is as follows:

[image]

The orange line represents $ \frac {4} {\pi} $ but there is no reason for it to be the limit, I did it for clickbait   :-\

Comment: Very interesting observation and question! (+1). But also this: https://xkcd.com/859/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limit equals $e^M$, where $M$ is the [Meissel–Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant):
\begin{align*}
M&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{p\leqslant n}\frac1p-\log\log n\right)
\\&\approx0.261497212847642783755426838608695859051566648+
\\e^M&\approx\color{blue}{1.29}8873321409030320833690880357295240469110387+
\\4/\pi&\approx\color{red}{1.27}3239544735162686151070106980114896275677166-
\end{align*}

To show the above, one may use $p(n)\asymp n\log n$ (essentially, it is the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Statement)) and $M_n:=\sum_{p\leqslant n}(1/p)\asymp\log\log n+M+\mathcal{O}(1/\log n)$ (this is [Mertens' second theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems)). These give
\begin{align*}
M_{p(n)}&\asymp\log\log n+M+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right),
\\e^{M_{p(n)}}&\asymp e^M\log n\left[1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)\right],
\\\sum_{k=1}^n e^{M_{p(k)}}&\asymp e^M \log(n!)+\mathcal{O}(n\log\log n),
\end{align*}
and the result follows after the division by $p(n)\asymp n\log n\asymp\log (n!)$.

Comment: great answer, thank you very much!